# How to overload dereference operator?

Tags: c++, class

How do I overload the dereference operator? What would the declaration look like? I'm creating a list class, but I am have trouble with the dereference operator.

Here is my function for overloading the dereference operator

```
template <typename T>
T List_Iterator<T>::operator *(){
    return current_link->value;
}
```

This is the data members in my iterator class

```
private:
      /* Data Members */
    Link<T>* current_link;
```

This is my link class

```
protected:
    T value;
```

Comment: That looks like the correct syntax to me. Could you explain what problem you're having?

Comment: Do you get an error? What is not working as you expected?

Comment: You may want to do that by reference and/or const-reference. Making a copy of T's in your list is bound to cause wtf-isms later on

Comment: You might want to return a reference so you can use the iterator to modify the value (e.g. `*it = whatever`). Apart from that, what trouble are you having?

Comment: Also covered in one of the *many* operator overloading suggestions [in this question and answer(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421719#4421719). Look for "Operators for Pointer-like Types", of which your iterator is one.

Comment: Even if I return by reference, the value it returns is just garbage. I can't get it to return the value of the 'value' variable in the Link class.

Answer (score 8):

You should be returning a reference, not a copy:

```
T& List_Iterator<T>::operator *() { .... }
```

Otherwise the semantics are confusing: you could not modify the object that you are "de-referencing".

Answer (score 0):

You can also return by address. It's easier to write `a->b` than `(*a).b` :

```
T* operator->() {
    return &current_link->value;
}
```

You will certainly need a const-version of your iterator, that will basically do the same thing as the first one, with the `const` versions of the "dereferencing" operators.